Safe and Sound with confusion
I know "safe and sound" means

completely safe and without injury or damage

So, can't we just use "safe"? is it the same meaning?
If I am safe, am I safe and sound and vice-versa?
and what does the "sound" part really mean?
Can I be safe but not sound or I am not safe but sound?

sound means "whole, in one piece, not broken, uninjured" related to German GeSUNDheit.

Sound in that collocation means free from injury or disease / free from flaw, defect, or decay, which is NOT the same as safe.

The collocation is "safe and sound".  Reversing it would sound strange.  Of course you can leave off "sound" but it won't have the full meaning of "out of harm's way and unharmed".
If you're bitten by a dog frothing at the mouth but manage to climb a tree to safety, you're safe, but not sound.

Is there an example for being "not safe but sound"?

A good example of that is Edgar Allen Poe's The Masque of the Red Death. The soundness is temporary :-)

There are various English idioms like this, consisting of two similar adjectives - home and dry, right and proper etc.

@holydragon If a dog is growling at you, you're sound (because they haven't bitten you yet) but not safe.
